# Netbeans cannot connect to MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I have search everywhere for the solution to this problem.

I used to have Netbeans 8.0 32-bit, Java 7 32-bit and MSSQL 2012. I already set up several connection in Server/Database in Netbeans and it was working perfectly. When I install Android Studio it required 64-bit version of Java so I uninstall my old version and install Java 8 64-bit. But Netbeans cannot detect the new version so I uninstall it and install Netbeans 8.1 64-bit. But when I try to connect using my old connection or even create new one, it always say: "Unable to connect. Connection refuse: connect. Verify the connection properties." My access to MSSQL stay the same, using the same username and password, already check the TCP/IP of MSSQL to be 1433, and turn off windows firewall. The only thing I don't know how to check is the host, which used to be 127.0.0.1.

Any way to solve this problem? Should I reverse my Java and Netbeans to 32-bit? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Connecting to MSSQL using NetBeans**

[Follow the steps given in this link](http://ruby.fgcu.edu/courses/mpenderg/GettingStartedWithNetbeans/SQLSERVERandNetbeans.html)

More resources which are available [on SO are here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892783/connecting-to-sql-server-from-netbeans)

One thing to note here is that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8.

Comment: As I mention in the question, I already have created several connections and they were working perfectly before the change (can connect and make sql query from Netbeans project to the database). So it seem that Java 8 was the problem, I make a fresh install of everything and config according to the link given and it working now

Comment: Cool. So are you on Java 7 at the moment?